# JS FB:Wall not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Im trying to integrate a facebook wall on my .net powered website using the following plugin.
http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall

Ive tried the following and nothing seems to be working, all the scripts are in the correct location and I cant seem to find a problem.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="facebook.aspx.cs" Inherits="facebook" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Facebook</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="_includes/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script> 
    <link href="_includes/css/jquery.neosmart.fb.wall.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="_includes/js/jquery.neosmart.fb.wall.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#live-demo').fbWall({
            id: '165674747098261',
            accessToken: '206158599425293|7809823973348bcf8cd72f6d.1-100000465435225|BW9n2eoyL7EYvJs7GEmv61NbBFk',
            showGuestEntries: true,
            showComments: true,
            max: 5,
            timeConversion: 24
        });


    </script>

</head>
<body>
<p>hello</p>
  <div id="live-demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ive added an alert at the end of my jquery to see if its processing which it is so im still unsure what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the `$(document).ready(function(){//your FB.wall code//});` this is the [DOM-thing](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready) to make the code run when page is ready.

Comment: Been searching for a way to make this work for hours. Your answer solved my problem. Thanks!